# Is the addition of two Automorphisms an Automorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I was wondering if the addition of two automorphisms is an automorphism.
Just to be clear , I'm talking about ring automorphisms.
Help appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adding any two automorphisms results in a map sending $1$ to $1+1$. Unless $1+1=1$ - and hence $0=1$, so our ring is trivial - this means the sum is not an automorphism.

So, in fact, the sum of automorphisms is **never** an automorphism *(unless our ring is the trivial ring, in which case who cares)*.

Similarly, the product of automorphisms is rarely an automorphism: $\alpha\times\beta$ will have to send $1+1$ to $1+1+1+1$, and this can only happen if $1+1=0$. That said, if $1+1=0$ and our ring is commutative then the *square* of any automorphism is again an automorphism *(exercise: think about what the equation $1+1=0$ says about the equation $(x+y)^2=x^2+xy+yx+y^2$ if our ring is commutative ...)*.

- What can you say about the product of *any two* automorphisms if our ring is commutative and satisfies $1+1=0$?
- Can you find an example of a *non*-commutative ring satisfying $1+1=0$?

Comment: What if $R$ has no unit? (As far as I can see the OP doesn't assume that $R$ is unital.)

Comment: @user26857 Note that this doesn't impact the question the OP asked. That said, I don't immediately see a non-unital proof of the product fact I mention, so that could be interesting. (That said, my impression is that rings are much more frequently assumed to be unital than not, although this isn't my field so I could be wrong.)